# replacing a promise string not executed

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, promise

I'm trying to replace all instances of 'formattedTime' in a [massive string](https://gyazo.com/3f533a5f18b554301437f5445b1e25ee).
Here's my code

```
googleTrends.interestOverTime({keyword: selectedTopic})
    .then((results) => {
    results.replace(/formattedTime/g, 'no what the heck');
    console.log(results);
})
    .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Oh no there was an error', err);
});
```

I am not receiving any errors however nothing is happening inside my console.
I even tried replacing a single line string but none of it will work. It might be because of the promise I'm receiving?
I am relatively new to RegEx so I thought maybe that was an issue but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: The replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced; thus update or return the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Strig.prototype.replace` does not mutate the string. Strings are immutable. It will return a new string.